# Use value of variable rather than keyword in python numpy.savez

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keyword

[numpy.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez)

In the last example, using savez with **kwds, the arrays are saved with the keyword names.

```
outfile = TemporaryFile()
np.savez(outfile, x=x, y=y)
outfile.seek(0)
npzfile = np.load(outfile)
npzfile.files
['y', 'x']
npzfile['x']
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

How would I use the actual value of a variable, such that:

```
x_name = 'foo'
y_name = 'bar'

np.savez(outfile, x_name=x, y_name=y)
```

Then

```
npzfile.files
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Where would the actual content of `npzfile.foo` and `.bar` come from?

Comment: I'm reading a bunch of images from a file path and extracting descriptors and ideally I would like the keys in the dictionary (image file names) to match to the descriptor. See what I mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a dictionary and then use `**` to pass its contents in the form of keyword arguments to `np.savez`.  For example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> x_name = 'foo'
>>> y_name = 'bar'
>>> outfile = TemporaryFile()
>>> np.savez(outfile, **{x_name: x, y_name: y})
>>> outfile.seek(0)
>>> npzfile = np.load(outfile)
>>> npzfile.files
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Yeah cool this seems to be working, I have C and C++ knowledge and know about pointers so I was thinking that I would have to pass a pointer but didn't know how to approach this in python. Thanks!